# Как сделать, чтобы нижестоящие блоки div не двигались?

Tags: html, css

Есть несколько блоков `div`, идущие подряд сверху вниз. Каждый содержит некоторый текст. При событии `hover` на `div` текст увеличивается с `11 px` до `13 px`, при этом высота `div` немного увеличивается, из-за чего все нижестоящие `div` съезжают вниз, но это некрасиво, так как получается, что вся страница прыгает. 
Как можно сделать, чтобы нижестоящие блоки не съезжали вниз? Задать фиксированную высоту `div` я не могу, т.к. все `div` разной высоты. Может быть можно как-то задать блоку `div` заранее высоту, которую он принимает при увеличении текста внутри `div`?

Comment: может такой вариант подойдет - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/1wbr4e3x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если дублирование контента допустимо, то можно воспользоваться таким трюком:

- создать блок, который будет служить контейнером
- внутри контейнера разместить прозрачный блок с целевым размером шрифта, он будет служить распоркой
- внутри контейнера разместить видимый блок с абсолютным позиционированием и размерами, равными размеру контейнера, над которым будут проводится преобразования

Этот трюк позволит оперировать любыми размерами строки.

Ниже раскадровка для пояснения:

- только блок распорка
- целевой блок поверх распорки
- только целевой блок

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hover-me {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.hover-me .visible {
  font-size: 11px;
}
.hover-me .visible:hover {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.visible {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.demo-1 .hidden,
.demo-2 .hidden {
  opacity: .25;
}
```

```html
<div class="hover-me demo-1">
  <div class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt alias, natus perspiciatis ipsum aspernatur quae dignissimos atque dolorum blanditiis asperiores!</div>
</div>
<div class="hover-me demo-2">
  <div class="visible">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat quidem laborum et nam sit eaque, magni reiciendis libero quia, corporis.</div>
  <div class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat quidem laborum et nam sit eaque, magni reiciendis libero quia, corporis.</div>
</div>
<div class="hover-me demo-3">
  <div class="visible">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae eveniet neque soluta ducimus veniam harum aliquam tempora doloribus. Consequuntur, atque.</div>
  <div class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae eveniet neque soluta ducimus veniam harum aliquam tempora doloribus. Consequuntur, atque.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю на сколько это вообще легально, но попробуйте использовать line-height со значением шрифта при увеличении. Например так: https://jsfiddle.net/7xLf31mo/

```
<div>
<span>Текст</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>Текст<br>текст</span>
</div>

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div{
  widhth: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 13px;
}
```